# jQuery - Getting color from an element and use it to another with opacity

Tags: jquery, css, colors, get, opacity

Basically I want to get the color from an CSS element (in our case #button)* and use it to another CSS element (in our case #output)* but with opacity . I want the output in **rgba** so I can set the opacity from **rgba**. My solution seems it doesn't want to work ...

```
function hex2rgb(hex, opacity) {
   var h=hex.replace('#', '');
   h =  h.match(new RegExp('(.{'+h.length/3+'})', 'g'));

   for(var i=0; i<h.length; i++)
   h[i] = parseInt(h[i].length==1? h[i]+h[i]:h[i], 16);

   if (typeof opacity != 'undefined')  h.push(opacity);

   return 'rgba('+h.join(',')+')';
}

var getcolor = $("#button").css("color");

var colour = hex2rgb(getcolor,0.3);

$(function() {
  $("#output").css("backgroundColor",colour); 
});
```

*see **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNp8C/11/)**

Comment: first of all there is no element with the `#element` in your demo. Secondly, what are you trying to do with `h[i] = parseInt(h[i].length == 1 ? h[i] + h[i] : h[i], 16);`?

Comment: there is no `id=button` in demo. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Okay guys, sorry, edited, #button .

Comment: @TJ I am trying to get the color from #button to #output but I have no idea how to get the color from #button and translate it to #output with opacity. I know what by default when you get a color from a CSS element , you get in in rgb and I want to add alpha beside the rgb to the new #output .

Comment: @charlietfl Look again please.

Comment: Why not [directly set the opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26078377/2333214) instead?

Comment: @tj Because the content that would be on the #output will be transparent too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the `rgb`, you can use the `opacity` property as shown below:

```js
function change(source, target, alpha) {
    var color = source.css("color");
    var sub = color.slice(0,-1).replace("rgb","rgba");
    color = sub+ ", "+alpha+")";
    target.css("background-color", color);
}

$(function () {
    change($("#button"),$("#output"), 0.5)
});
```

```css
#output {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:#ff0; /* This needs to be replaced with #button color to rgba */
}

#button {
    color:#F54C54;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<br>
<div id="button">Get color from this text</div>
```

Comment: I am in need of rgba output, I want to set the opacity from RGBA - don't want to use Opacity instead.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like your code works at all. If I've understood your requirement, something like this would work:

```
$.fn.extend({
    stealColor : function(target, opacity)
    {
        $(this).css('background-color', $(target).css('background-color') )
               .css('opacity', opacity );     

    } 
});

$('#output').stealColor('#button', 0.8);
```

Or if you want to steal the text color:

```
$(this).css('background-color', $(target).css('color') )
    .css('opacity', opacity );
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hkyfpmu/).

Your original function hex2rgb takes an rgb() parameter and produces an rgba() value.

So, to fix your code:

```
function rgb2rgba(rgb, opacity) {
    return 'rgba' + rgb.substring(3, rgb.length-1) + ', ' + opacity + ')';
}
var getcolor = $("#button").css("color");
var colour = rgb2rgba(getcolor, 0.3);
$("#output").css("background-color", colour);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vphznba/).

Comment: I will use this in "worst case scenario" I need the output in RGBA I want to set the opacity from RGBA.